# How to handle chunked response in Jetty's transparent proxy servlet

Tags: jetty, reverse-proxy, chunked-encoding

I'm using `Jetty 9.4.9.v20180320`. I have implemented `Reverse Proxy` by extending `Transparent` servlet. I have overridden `rewriteTarget` and `filterServerResponseHeader` methods

```
  public class ServicesProxyServlet extends Transparent {
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

@Override
protected String rewriteTarget(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...
    return rewrittenURI;
}

@Override
protected String filterServerResponseHeader(HttpServletRequest clientRequest, Response serverResponse, String headerName, String headerValue) {
        ...
    return super.filterServerResponseHeader(clientRequest, serverResponse, headerName, headerValue);
}
}
```

The destination server sends `chunked` response at given interval of time.

Now, it seems the `Transparent proxy` receives the whole response before sending it to client which causes the client timeout with `504 Gateway Timeout`. If I removed `filterServerResponseHeader` the error still occurs.

I expect to send the chunked response to client without buffering it in `Transparent proxy`. This would avoid client timeout. How to flush the received data immediately in `Transparent proxy`? How to handle this?

Comment: You should be using `AsyncProxyServlet.Transparent` (not `ProxyServlet.Transparent`), and an up to date version of Jetty (9.4.9 is old).

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I changed to `AsyncProxyServlet.Transparent`. I've overridden `onResponseContent` and used `HttpServletResponse.response.flushBuffer()`. This flushes header immediately. I have tried `response.getOutputStream().flush();` This does not flush chunked response. How to flush chunked data upon receiving from server?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I followed [link](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-proxy/9.4.12.RC0/source-code/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/ProxyServlet.java) and overrided `onResponseContent` and added `response.getOutputStream().flush();` to this method. It is flushing content immediately. Is this method fine?

Comment: Your link points to 9.4.12.RC0 (which is a unstable Release Candidate), don't use that in production. use an official stable release.

Comment: I have not updated the jar. I have just override the method in the code given in question. So looking as a whole, to achieve reverse proxy I have created class by extending `AsyncProxyServlet.Transparent` and override 3 methods, `rewriteTarget`, `filterServerResponseHeader` and `onResponseContent`.